# SQL - select top xx% rows

Tags: sql, count, sum

I have a table, `sales`, which is ordered by descending `TotalSales`

```
user_id  |   TotalSales  
----------------------
4              10 
2              1.5 
5              0.99  
3              0.5    
1              0.33
```

What I would like to do is find the percentage of the sum of all sales that the xx% most important sales represent.
For example if I wanted to do it for top 40% sales, here I would get (10+1.5)/(10+1.5+0.99+0.5+0.33)= 86%
But right now I haven't been able to select "top xx% rows".

Edit: DB management system can be MySQL or Vertica or Hive

Comment: post the expected output for the table and which DBMS ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select Sum(a)  as s from sales where a in (Select TotalSales from sales where TotalSales>=x)

GROUP BY a


select Sum(TotalSales) as b from sales group by b
```

your result is `s/b`

and `x= the percentage you set each time`

Comment: Except I don't think `TotalSales` is a percentage - the OP wants `40%`, but the _total_ of that column isn't even 20.